# Why do we need DFT when we already have DTFT/DTFS?

Tags: discrete-signals, fourier-transform, algorithms, analog-to-digital

We already have DTFT so why do we need DFT?

Please don't write DTFT is used for discrete, aperiodic signal which transfers in the frequency domain to periodic and continuous, but in DFT is discrete periodic transfer in discrete periodic, these things I already know.

Comment: Because we have efficient algorithms to compute the DFT, and the DFT can be used to approximate the DTFT and the CTFT.

Comment: To help answers keeping focused: why are you suggesting that the DFT could be "not useful enough" ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The answer is the same to the question: *"Why do we need computers to process data when we have paper and pencil?"*

DTFT as well as the continuous-time Fourier Transform is a theoretical tool for infinitely long hypothetical signals.

the DFT is to observe the spectrum of actual data that is finite in size.

Comment: Don't forget the rulers and compasses!

Comment: So paper and pencil is a theoretical tool for infinitely long hypothetical signals?

Comment: @user253751 sure, write out the analytical form of the signal and then work out whatever algebra/calculus you need by hand.

Answer (score 15):

TL, DR: **world pervasive algorithms (FFT-related)**!

The continuous Fourier transform, the Discrete-time Fourier transform (DTFT) and the Discrete  Fourier transform (DFT) share conceptually similar traits (regarding energy, convolution, shift, scale, etc.)

The DFT unveiled a very scalable and fast algorithm to put those concepts into practice: the FFT. It is considered by many to be one of the most important algorithms, and is in the lists below:

- [The Most Important Algorithms](https://www3.risc.jku.at/people/ckoutsch/stuff/e_algorithms.html): "Fast Fourier transform (FFT):
  Efficient algorithm to compute the discrete Fourier transform (DFT) and its inverse. FFTs are of great importance to a wide variety of applications, from digital signal processing to solving partial differential equations to algorithms for quickly multiplying large integers. "
- [15 of the Most Important Algorithms That Helped Define Mathematics, Computing, and Physics](https://interestingengineering.com/15-of-the-most-important-algorithms-that-helped-define-mathematics-computing-and-physics): "6. Fast Fourier Transform Breaks Down Signals Into Frequencies"
- [The five most important algorithms?](https://lemire.me/blog/2010/07/05/the-five-most-important-algorithms/): "The Fast Fourier transform (FFT) is an amazing algorithm. Combined with the Convolution theorem, it lets you do magic."

Of course, Google PageRank, the Euclidian division, Quicksort, Kalman filtering are used daily. But if we include digital data compression, for instance: [MP3 Compression/The 10 Algorithms That Dominate Our World](https://io9.gizmodo.com/the-10-algorithms-that-dominate-our-world-1580110464), or JPEG decoding, as while not directly DFTs, but very close avatars which might not have been discovered without the DFT, I am pretty sure that billions of DFT-inspired algorithms are run every hour.
In 2012 (source: [A Faster Fast Fourier Transform: New algorithm crunches sparse data with speed](https://spectrum.ieee.org/computing/software/a-faster-fast-fourier-transform)), Richard Baraniuk was already credited with "FFTs are run billions of times a day", and Gilbert Strang:

> once  referred to the fast Fourier transform, or FFT, as “the most
> important numerical algorithm in our lifetime"

Comment: How many quicksorts run per hour?

Comment: People used tables by ID so often... I could not find numbers

Answer (score 1):

To overcome the limitation of DTFT we use DFT tool. it is almost similar to DTFT but only limitation is the infinite length sequence.